# Identify first occurence of vector where 12 of 15 values are 1

Tags: r, rle

I have a vector like so:

```
test = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1)
```

and within this vector I want to identify the first time that 12 of 15 values is equal to one.

I have started by using `rle` to count the consecutive values:

```
#get counts of sequences
count = rle(test)
```

and then getting a sequence based on this:

```
#make a sequence of the counts
new <- sequence(count$lengths)
```

I will then turn any values in `new` to 0 where a `test` value is equal to NA:

```
#when the value was na make the count 0
new[is.na(test)] <- 0
```

and lastly I will change all other values to 1:

```
#make all other counts 1
new[new !=0] <- 1
```

which will return:

```
 [1] 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

this is where I am stuck, now I know the index location where the first time 12 out of 15 values is 1 is idx = 6, but I am stuck on how to retrieve it with an algorithm.

Comment: Are you interested in the index of ones first time reaching the count 12? How did you come to index = 6?

Comment: If you start at idx = 6 and move 15 places over you will see this is the first time 12 of 15 consecutive values = 1.  Thanks @akrun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `rollapply` to do the `sum` of logical vector, and get the index of first match where the sum is 12 with `match`

```
library(zoo)
match(12, rollapply(test, width = 15, FUN = function(x) sum(x== 1, na.rm = TRUE)))
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `zoo::rollsum` to find the first point where the next 15 values sum to 12 or more.

```r
which(zoo::rollsum(test, 15, align = "left", fill = 0) >= 12)[1]
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>